# EntityManager.find();

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

Всем привет. Изучаю Hibernate.
К примеру если я хочу из базы данных юзеров найти одного юзера по айди, то вопросов нету:

```
Client client = em.find(Client.class, id);
```

А если я хочу найти клиента по другим параметрам, к примеру одновременно по имени  и номеру телефона?

Вот к примеру у меня есть сущность клиент

class User {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

@Column(name = "name",nullable = false, length = 32)
private String name;

@Column(name = "number", nullable = false, unique = true)
private String number;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
private Set<Account>accounts;

User(String name, String number) {
    this.name = name;
    this.number = number;
}
```

}

а теперь  я хочу найти его с помощью ентити менеджера? 
Может создать мапу в которой будут параметры поиска? Но как тогда менеджер поймет по каким полям и как сравнивать?

```
 System.out.println("write your username");
    String username = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("write your number");
    String number = scanner.nextLine();
    Map<String, Object> map= new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("username", username);
    map.put("number", number);

    User user = entityManager.find(User.class, map);
```

Так вот, что делать? Или тогда создать запрос с которого вытянуть всех клиентов, а тогда перебрать по критериям?

Answer (score 1):

Вытягивать всех клиентов можно, если у вас их меньше 100 например, да и то будет не оптимально: ни по скорости, ни по памяти.
Вы можете попробовать использовать Query, например:

```
TypedQuery<User> query = em.createQuery(
            "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.username = :username AND u.number = :number", User.class);
    User user = query.setParameter("username", username)
                         .setParameter("number", number)
                         .getSingleResult();
```

или

```
List<User> users = query.setParameter("username", username)
                                     .setParameter("number", number)
                                     .getResultList();
```